# Data submitted to GA account doesn't appear in there

Tags: javascript, browser, google-analytics, e-commerce

I **need to manually** submit an ecommerce data to my Google Analytics Account, so I created an html file and opened in a browser:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1', 'auto'); 
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce');
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': 'storeId123_test_cartId123_test_1426000599',
  'affiliation': '',
  'revenue': '352429',
  'shipping': '334433',
  'tax': '3344'
});

  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': 'storeId123_test_cartId123_test_1426000599',
  'name': 'title_123',
  'sku': 'sku_123',
  'category': 'some_category',
  'price': '444',
  'quantity': '33'
});

  ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

But I don't any data in my GA account. How come?

[image]

Comment: Transactions won't show right away in your standard reports; you may need to wait at least 24 hours for data to be processed.

Comment: @nyuen, is that mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: No explicitly, but in general, GA data takes anywhere from 24-48 hours to be processed into your standard reports (could be shorter, too, as I've noticed data sometimes processed in a few hours). You can, in some cases, check real-time reports, but I ecomm data isn't supported in those reports.

Comment: Processing time is in the documentation: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en

Comment: @EikePierstorff, thanks. Since  I'm sending it manually and there may some errors, how do I check if it reaches GA at all before 24-48 hours have passed?

Comment: Not sure you can. You can install the Chrome Google Analytics Debugger extension and make sure that the data is sent, but you can't look at it in the reports until it's processed.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, please take a look at my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems that you call this page locally from the filesystem. This does not work by default since Analytics cannot write cookies unless the page is served by a web server.

It should work if you change the cookie domain parameter from "`auto`" to "`none`", but it might be better to push the file to a webserver (or set up something like XAMPP locally) as I'm not sure where that second error ("Error loading resource") comes from; GA cannot load the ecommerce tracking library and that might very well be a problem with the local file system as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982806/running-google-analytics-on-localhost-error-loading-the-plugin -- I will put it on the server, but first I need to make sure it's working locally, otherwise how could I debug it? Anyway, wouldn't it load the file (ecommerce) while on the localhost? It's just a normal file and it's available.

Comment: I asked another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982806/running-google-analytics-on-localhost-error-loading-the-plugin the error isn't resolved yet, please take a look.