# Running Google Analytics on localhost - error loading the plugin

Tags: javascript, browser, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have this code to be executed from an html file which sends data to Google Analytics. The code itself is in a file on the localhost and I'm opening it in a browser. So it's not on the webserver.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
  alert('hello123');
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');


  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'none');
  ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null); 
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  // ga('require', 'ecommerce');
  ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

  /*ecommerce*/
  ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': 'storeId123_test_cartId123_test_1426000599',
  'affiliation': '',
  'revenue': '352429',
  'shipping': '334433',
  'tax': '3344'
});

  ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': 'storeId123_test_cartId123_test_1426000599',
  'name': 'title_123',
  'sku': 'sku_123',
  'category': 'some_category',
  'price': '444',
  'quantity': '33'
});

  ga('ecommerce:send',{'hitCallback': function() {alert("ecommerce");}});

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I have the errors:

1) Error loading resource for plugin "ecommerce": Refusing to load url: "http://www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ua/ecommerce.js"

although that url is avaible.

2) Storage not available. Aborting hit -- but I have 'none' in ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'none');

The main error is the first one, I believe the 2nd is related to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the combination of cookie domain "none" and the ecommerce-plugin does not work. I haven't delved deeply enough into the tracking code to find out why this is so, I have simply tested it - when I save your code in a file an place it on a web server the ecommerce tracking fails with "none" and works with "auto".

This means if you want to test E-Commerce Tracking Code you cannot do so from the filesystem. I would recommend you set up a local webserver (I like [XAMPP], which[1](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/index.html) includes apache, mysql and php and runs on Windows and Mac) and test your code from there.

Comment: it worked with auto for you? It gave me an error "unable to write cookie".

Comment: Of course. But I have an error in your example "GET http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"

Comment: It's working. However, it's a half of I'm trying to do. I need to execute that code, yes, on the server, but not the normal browser like Chrome - in "headless browser". That's why I've been trying to execute it on localhost in the filesystem first.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to verify if it's working in "headless browser"? I've run the code using it but since it was a normal browser, I couldn't, of course, use google analytics debugger.

Comment: Frankly I would recommend the measurement protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference), that way it doesn't matter from where you send your request.

Comment: It seems like what I need, but didn't find anything related to ecommerce. So can it be used to achieve exactly the same thing what http://bit.ly/1C4u5CG is doing?

Comment: Yes, if you look into the parameter reference (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ecomm) you will find the ecommerce tracking.